# Mysql, deleting row in form loop

Tags: php, mysql, database

I dont now where my mistake is, my code is as follows:

```
<?php

mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obedy ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 30");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) 
{
    $time = strtotime( $row[0] );
    $myDate = date( 'd.m.', $time );
    $w_day = date( 'N', $time );
    $ww_day = $w_day-1;
    $the_row= $row[0];

    echo "<p>" . $myDate . "&emsp;";
    echo "<input type='hidden' value='$row[0]' name='tdel'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='menu1' id='menu1' class='input' value='". $row[1] ."' size='37'/>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='menu2' id='menu2' class='input' value='". $row[2] ."' size='37'/>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='menu3' id='menu3' class='input' value='". $row[3] ."' size='37'/>";
    echo "<input type='submit' formaction='del_menu.php' class='button' value='Smazat' />";
    echo "</p>";                    
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

del_menu.php

```
<?php

$huh = mysql_connect("juxcore.ipagemysql.com", "*", "*") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("jux_mms");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$watta="DELETE FROM obedy WHERE datum = '$_POST[tdel]'";

if (!mysql_query($watta,$huh))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

header('Location: http://www.juxcore.com/x/vita/menu.php');
```

The thing is, I don't know why it deletes the last displayed row, instead the one clicked. Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See
 the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: Your form is going to have multiple entries called `tdel`. When you hit submit, they're all sent to the server, and each one over-rides the preceding one, so the last one is the one that's processed.

Comment: Are you wrapping each separate form in a `<form>` tag?

Comment: @lc. that's where I got confused, he is using HTML5 `formaction='del_menu.php'`

Comment: @lc. yes i am: <form method='post' action='del_menu.php'> </form>

Comment: @user1505027 - that's not in your code. Are you wrapping that whole while loop in a single form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `<form>` tags:

```
echo "<form action='del_menu.php' method='post'><p>" . $myDate . "&emsp;";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$row[0]."' name='tdel'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='menu1' id='menu1_".$row[0]."' class='input' value='". $row[1] ."' size='37'/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='menu2' id='menu2_".$row[0]."' class='input' value='". $row[2] ."' size='37'/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='menu3' id='menu3_".$row[0]."' class='input' value='". $row[3] ."' size='37'/>";
echo "<input type='submit'  class='button' value='Smazat' />";
echo "</p></form>";
```

The problem is that you can only have one item with the same name in one form. If you use multiple items with the same name, only the last one defined will get trough. You can use multiple forms to solve that.

Comment: Oh, I see, I should place them INSIDE the loop. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: if you put `<form>` there you are including it in the loop